# Как разделить строку на слова на PL/pgSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Как разделить строку на список слов разделённых пробелами на PL/pgSQL?

Например, в функцию приходит:

`'I like apple'`

Как сделать, чтобы к переменным присваивались эти слова?

```
 var1 = 'I'
 var2 = 'like'
 var3 = 'apple'
```

Я пользуюсь postgreSQL 11.

Comment: приведите код функции пожалуйста

Comment: @lex-hobbit Нет кода функции. Я поэтому и спрашиваю этот вопрос.

Comment: а для чего целевая функция нужна, просто можно разделить и сложить все слова в массив или предполагается какая-то обработка каждого слова в отдельности?

Comment: @lex-hobbit Всё верно Вы говорите, я хочу обрабатывать каждое слово по отдельности

Comment: @Lumberspin попробуйте regexp_split_to_array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

с массивом будет лучше, так как слов может быть не три, а больше или меньше.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    _arr text[];
BEGIN
    SELECT regexp_split_to_array('I like apple', '\s+')
    INTO _arr;

тут делаем что надо с элементами массива

END $$
```